# adding border around UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I tried adding a border to my UITableViewCell however when two UITableViewCell are against each other, it seems that the border collides (the top border of the bottom cell vs the bottom border of the top cell) and therefore it makes the border twice as thick as it's needed. Is there a way around of doing this?

Comment: Are these grouped or plain `UITableViewCell`s?  Also, what is the visual effect that you want to achieve that the separator does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top border of top cell should have the correct width, bottom border of bottom cell should have correct width. Top border of bottom cell, bottom border of top cell and top+bottom of all middle cells should have half width.

Hopes this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds logical to me. Without a separator the two cells are located next to each other. The bottom line of the border of the first cell touches the top line of the second cell.

If you want each cell to have its own border then you could simply leave a pixel (point resprectively) free at the bottom of each cell or you leave a margin on both sides, top and bottom.

The easiest would be not to change anything to the drawing but to add a point or two to the heitght of the cell. (Well, depending on your code of course.)

If you want just one line between the cells then you could omit the bottom line in each cell but the last one. Or for the last one you could draw the line within the table footer (for tables with one section only).

Answer (score 0):

Try to give rounded border to tableView which can differentiate your table.Use below displayed code

```
CALayer * l1 = [tableView layer];
[l1 setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l1 setCornerRadius:10.0];
[l1 setBorderWidth:2.0];
```